# How to enable the Federated/FederatedX storage engine on MariaDB 5.5?

Tags: mysql-5.5, mariadb

I upgraded from MySQL 5.1 to MariaDB 5.3 and then to 5.5 on a Windows machine. Everything works well, except I can't enable the federated storage engine. 
With MySQL 5.1 and MariaDB 5.3, I just added "federated" under [mysqld]. If I try to start MariaDB 5.5 with the same "federated" option, I get an error:

> C:\Program Files\MariaDB 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown option '--federated'

How can I enable the federated storage engine?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-federatedx/ ?

Comment: I did, but didn't see any relevant information there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer in a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399130/1351416). I missed one command that I didn't see documented anywhere:

```
install plugin federated soname 'ha_federated.so'
```

Just had to change `ha_federated.so` to `ha_federatedx` and run in a client and it works!

Comment: thanks, as the old federated (ha_federated) is also working but slowly.

Answer (score 1):

FederatedX is enabled by default in MariaDB 5.5

Comment: `show engines` doesn't list it, and I get an error when trying to created a federated table "Unknown storage engine".