# Why does INSERTing to a federatedx table fail silently?

Tags: mariadb, xampp, federated-table

For testing, I've set up a XAMPP portable 8.1.12 with `10.4.27-MariaDB` and enabled the FederatedX engine using [this trick](https://gist.github.com/ayel07/8a0bf8dd03b8e7ab5a607d2bcf16d133).

When I now set up a `SERVER` that is not existing and a federated table that is "using" that server, running a `SELECT` against that table fails as it should, but `INSERT` behaves as if it has worked. Why is that?

Example:

```
CREATE SERVER `nonexistentserver`
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER `nonexistentserverwrapper`
OPTIONS (
    HOST '127.0.0.1',
    DATABASE 'thereIsNoServerSoThereIsNoDatabase', 
    USER 'andNoUser',
    PASSWORD 'AndNoPassword!',
    PORT 12345
);

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    theLine INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    theContent VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='nonexistentserver/mytable';
```

`SELECT` behaves as I would expect:

```
MariaDB [testdb]> SELECT * FROM mytable;
ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 10000 'Error on remote system: 0: ' from FEDERATED
```

But `INSERT` does not:

```
MariaDB [testdb]> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (NULL, "Hey!");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.005 sec)
```

Is that a bug or is it supposed to do that?

---

**Additum 1:**

When I do not use `install plugin federated soname 'ha_federatedx';` but remove the `x` first (inspiration from [this answer plus comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52279/199100)), thus use *the old federated* but federatedX, the `INSERT` gives the expected error.

Comment: I [Can't see an existing bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22insert%22%20and%20component%20%3D%22Storage%20Engine%20-%20Federated%22%20%20%20and%20status!%3DClosed). You could create a new one. The [connect engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/introduction-to-the-connect-engine/) is more maintained at the moment and likely to stay that way.